Dell XPS 9315 on Ubuntu 20.04 with drawnout shutdown
Has anyone recently experienced problems with Dell or other PC's on shutdown? Some days ago, coinciding with the worldwide Windows/Crowdstrike problems, I am now experiencing a strange shutdown of my PC. It doesn't turn off almost immediately, but hangs for some time showing "Safe Bios with Dell", as if starting up again, and then writes a very long script at the end, before shutting down completely. I cannot read what is written to the screen, as it is there for a very short time. Somewhere I read that it could be a config problem in systemd, where I could edit the config file and set shutdown to max 30 seconds. But I cannot edit and save the file, no permission. It could be Snap Daemon running wild (omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/03/fix-ubuntu-slow-shutdowns-snap-daemon ), says the same comment I read. Any suggestions?

Suggest that you contact Dell. The only real info in your question is about the Dell BIOS. Please edit the question and add the URL where you got the comments from telling you it is a systemd or Snap running wild issue.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/03/fix-ubuntu-slow-shutdowns-snap-daemon

I looked at that link and I have to say the guy is a clown. Also his fix of kill off snap is a very bad idea. Strange I have never come across nor can I find anyone on this site reporting this kind of issue with Snap. I did add the link to your question so if others want to read it they can, at least for as long as it is up.

Ok, so I'll wait and see if anyone has a good suggestion.

Thank God for Timeshift. My problem with a faulty shutdown, where Ubuntu tries to restart several times, and all ends with a huge display of something, has not gone away, even after changing Stop to 10s in systemd/system.conf. So I reverted to a Tiimeshift from 2 weeks ago, and ít went back to version 113, from the current 117:                  "System:
Host: DELLMIN Kernel: 5.15.0-113-generic x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"                         So I await a fix of fixes in 117. Second time I have been saved by a Timeshift.

Many times the shutdown on my Dell laptop (which runs XUBUNTU) is quite slow.
The cause is having mounts to other systems within my network, especially if those mounts are currently unavailable.
A specific example:  During the day I make reference to a share on one of the house systems from my Dell laptop.  I shut that house system down for the night.  I forget that my Dell laptop still has a reference to a SAMBA share on that house system I shutdown earlier.  I now issue a shutdown on the Dell laptop - that's when it's going to take some time for the laptop to shutdown.
